# square od combinatprial in discrete math

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, combinatorial-proofs

I have the following question:
I am trying to prove that
$\sum_{k=0}^{n} {\binom{N}{k}}^2 = \binom{2N}{k}$.

I tried proving by induction $\sum_{k=0}^{n} {\binom{N}{k}}^2$,

so I substituted k = 0 , 1,2,3,4..n, and I got
$\sum_{k=0}^{n} {\binom{N}{k}}^2= 1 + n^2 + 0.25(n^4-2n^3+n^2)+..+(1/n!)^2$
now I dunno how to move farther.
Should I be doing the same with the other term to prove them equal

Comment: Hi, welcome. I edited your question, you have to use the $ sign to add latex. You can edit your question to check how and correct the rest of the question.

Comment: What do you mean by $k$ in the RHS? $k$ is the integer "variable" of the LHS it isn't a fixed value

Comment: Also, probably that should be $n$ not $N$

Comment: my bad. you are right:

Comment: @Aryaaaaan my bad you are right. it should be like that . $\sum_{k=0}^{n} {\binom{n}{k}}^2 = \binom{2n}{n}$

Comment: Are you familiar with the notion of combinatorial proofs? Rewrite the LHS as the sum of ${n\choose k}{n\choose n-k}$ instead. The RHS counts the number of ways to choose $k$ elements from a set of $2n$ elements. Think of this set as being made of two halves, each containing $n$ elements. Can you see how the LHS counts the same thing?